# Watermark problem with CodeIgniter when I am trying to call a function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to watermark some images on upload by calling a function. However when I try doing so, I get the following error: `Unable to load the requested language file: language/default/imglib_lang.php` . The piece of code where I am trying to watermark the image is the following:

```
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';

    try {
        $image = new ImageResize($path);
        $image->quality_jpg = 85;
        $image->resizeToWidth(1920);
        $new_name = 'img_1920x_' . generate_unique_id() . '.jpg';
        $new_path = 'uploads/' . $folder . '/' . $new_name;

        $config['source_image'] = base_url($new_path);
        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 
        base_url('uploads/logo/waterLogo.png');
        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
        $config['width'] = '200';
        $config['height'] = '100';

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->watermark();

        $image->save(FCPATH . $new_path, IMAGETYPE_JPEG);

        return $new_name;
    } catch (ImageResizeException $e) {
        return null;
    }
```

If I am trying to use the watermark function in another place of the application I don't encounter this problem. What do you think I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get an error for what specific line of code is throwing the error? If so can you update your post with that information please?

Comment: unfortunately there is no line specified in the error

Comment: did you check if that language file exist? /language/default/imglib_lang.php, see also https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#language-class